# Set multiple values as pivot table filter criteria in vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to use VBA macros to automatically update a pivot table in a different workbook with specific filter values. There are approximately 10 values I am interested in looking at, but to start I would like to be able to view two at the same time. I am using variables to dynamically reference the workbook to open based on the month and week number. The line in question that isn't working is the very bottom one.

```
Dim varMonth As String
Dim varWeek As String
Worksheets("Data").Activate
varMonth = Range("B2").Value
varWeek = Range("B3").Value
Workbooks.Open("filepath" & varMonth & "/" & varMonth & " WK " & varWeek & " D1 Reconciliation.xlsx").Sheets("Pivot").Activate
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("D1Pivot").PivotFields("Marketing Referral Type").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("D1Pivot").PivotFields("Marketing Referral Type").CurrentPage = "Digital"
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("D1Pivot").PivotFields("Appointment Status").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("D1Pivot").PivotFields("Appointment Status").CurrentPage = "Showed/Day1" And "No Show"
```

I'm still getting acclimated to what VBA is capable of, so I'm wondering if it's a simple fix that I just don't see yet.

Comment: Sophia, did you try to record a macro to see the code generated by the changes you have done to the pivot table? Can you post some dummy data so we can see the structure you are working with?

Comment: Take a look at the examples on this link https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/manipulate-pivot-items-with-vba/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping through each pivotitem in your pivotfield, and then checking whether the name is either "Showed/Day1" or "No Show".  If not, set the Visible property of the pivotitem to False . . .

```
With Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("D1Pivot").PivotFields("Appointment Status")
    .ClearAllFilters
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    For Each pi In .PivotItems
        If pi.Name <> "Showed/Day1" And pi.Name <> "No Show" Then
            pi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
End With
```

However, your code can be re-written as follows...

```
With Worksheets("Data")

    Dim varMonth As String
    varMonth = .Range("B2").Value
    
    Dim varWeek As String
    varWeek = .Range("B3").Value
    
End With

Workbooks.Open "filepath" & varMonth & "/" & varMonth & " WK " & varWeek & " D1 Reconciliation.xlsx"

With Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("D1Pivot")

    With .PivotFields("Marketing Referral Type")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPage = "Digital"
    End With
    
    With .PivotFields("Appointment Status")
        .ClearAllFilters
        Dim pi As PivotItem
        For Each pi In .PivotItems
            If pi.Name <> "Showed/Day1" And pi.Name <> "No Show" Then
                pi.Visible = False
            End If
        Next pi
    End With
    
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That code worked perfectly for what I needed! I really appreciate your help, and for rewriting my code in an easier-to-read format.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad I could help, cheers!